# WPF Border not wrap Image Control in uniform stretch

Tags: wpf, image, border

I have a WPF Image Control and I would like a WPF Border around it. Problem is the destination dimensions is bigger than the image, so Image Control is set to Uniform Stretch to fit it inside. This is the code to do this:

```
<Border>
    <Image Stretch=Uniform Width="50" Height="50"/>
</Border>
```

When the Border is put around the Image Control, the Border doesn't know the Image is resized to fit the destination, so the Border goes all around the destination and there is gap between Border and Image (it is supposed to fully wrap on the image).

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Set `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` as Center on border. Default value is Stretch so it stretches to fill the entire grid.

```
<Border HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
   <Image Stretch=Uniform Width="50" Height="50"/>
</Border>
```